# I want my website to fit the screen height, though there's too less content

Tags: html, css

More specific I want the content section (the section with the white background) fill the mising space, so the header and footer have it's own fixed size and the content section is as big as it takes to fill/fit the full height.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Startseite - Malermeister Gen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de">
        <meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="21.10.2018 08:22:20"> <!-- Edit: Nach Abschluss der Arbeit aktualisieren! -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Til Jungbluth">
        <meta name="description" content="Hier wird eine Beschreibung stehen..."> <!-- Edit: Beschreibung hinzufuegen! -->
        <!-- <meta name="keywords" content="Malerorth, GmbH, Maler, Orth, Malermeister, Westerwald, Seck"> <!-- Edit: Ergaenzen! -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="headerWrapper">
                <header id="header">
                    <a href="index.html"><img id="headerLogo" src="img/Logo Malerinnung.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <h1 id="headerHeading">Malermeister Gen</h1>
                    <p id="headerSlogan"><span id="gestaltung">Gestaltung</span> - <span id="schoenheit">Schöhnheit</span> - <span id="schutz">Schutz</span></p>
                </header>
                <nav id="headerNav">
                    <a href="index.html" class="headerNavLinks" id="headerNavLinkActive">Home</a>
                    <a href="unser_team.html" class="headerNavLinks">Unser Team</a>
                    <a href="kontakt.html" class="headerNavLinks">Kontakt</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="contentWrapper">
                <h2 id="contentHeading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                <div id="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In mattis ligula ac dui rhoncus finibus. Duis sit amet sollicitudin lorem, id interdum nisi. Curabitur tincidunt odio vitae elit hendrerit, sit amet pellentesque nibh faucibus. Ut in molestie lectus, sed faucibus dui. Phasellus auctor finibus erat, eget iaculis nunc euismod in. Suspendisse rhoncus erat volutpat neque varius, a sodales ante pharetra. Sed ullamcorper dictum eros non porta. Nulla viverra enim id odio eleifend, eu malesuada est mollis.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus nec egestas dolor, a blandit nibh. Fusce sit amet volutpat turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum nunc erat, et finibus erat scelerisque sed. Praesent eget dolor dolor. Praesent sit amet nisi est. Vivamus augue purus, dapibus vitae velit et, ultricies commodo diam. Proin in justo sed mi molestie malesuada a eget enim. Donec venenatis posuere nisi. Fusce felis metus, scelerisque ut lacus ut, hendrerit porta magna.</p>
                    <p>Nullam dictum varius mi sit amet gravida. Sed tortor metus, bibendum et sem quis, aliquet lacinia dolor. Suspendisse eu enim eget metus tristique laoreet sit amet vel ligula. Sed risus diam, elementum ac est a, mollis porta lacus. Nullam in erat elementum, venenatis purus et, iaculis odio. Aenean et orci viverra, aliquet elit vel, blandit ipsum. Aenean id velit id tellus faucibus pretium et eu ipsum. Fusce ac libero ultricies, vestibulum eros vel, aliquam lectus. Nullam est magna, vestibulum rutrum enim a, ultricies auctor ipsum. Nunc consectetur, sem at facilisis lacinia, nibh libero pulvinar elit, et convallis massa ligula in libero. Etiam finibus imperdiet odio vel tristique. Vestibulum ornare nibh at justo dictum accumsan. Donec non sapien risus. Suspendisse sed ante vitae neque sollicitudin posuere. Fusce mollis dapibus rutrum.</p>
                    <p>Etiam vel odio est. Nulla quis urna bibendum, tincidunt est id, laoreet nulla. Nunc consequat, ante at blandit rutrum, nisl odio vestibulum est, ut aliquam ligula ligula in nulla. Quisque rutrum, lorem in posuere fringilla, lorem libero bibendum metus, vel aliquet ex urna sed sem. Donec quis nisi arcu. Nunc magna odio, mollis auctor tortor nec, tincidunt ornare magna. Aenean sagittis enim et libero condimentum, at pellentesque risus hendrerit. Quisque eget purus in dui semper dignissim blandit non dui. Etiam mollis vehicula nulla lacinia pretium. Ut cursus, libero eu vehicula dapibus, massa nisi venenatis ex, nec fermentum mi lacus in leo. Nunc massa orci, vestibulum in pellentesque vitae, suscipit at augue. Vestibulum tempus arcu at fermentum aliquet. Duis feugiat, lacus eu accumsan viverra, eros nisi sodales libero, non pulvinar ante erat id lorem. Phasellus mauris orci, condimentum in eros non, aliquam egestas erat. Etiam neque libero, imperdiet vitae lobortis id, ultrices efficitur ante.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer id="footer">
                <p id="footerP">© Malermeister Gen GmbH | 
                    <a href="kontakt.html" class="footerNavLinks">Kontakt</a> | 
                    <a href="impressum.html" class="footerNavLinks">Impressum</a>
                </p>
                <button onclick="topFunction()" id="scrollBackToTop" title="Go to top">Zum Seitenanfang</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 51, 145) 0%, rgb(241, 185, 0) 50%, rgb(212, 24, 0) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#header{
    height: 4.3em; /*Actual height is 4.1em. There was a space between #header and #headerNav, whyever...*/
    margin: 0 0 -0.2em 0; /*In this way they overlap, so there's no unwanted space between.*/
    padding: 0.6em;
    background: darkgrey;
}

#headerLogo{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#headerHeading{
    margin: 0 0 0 0.4em;
    display: inline-block;
}

#headerSlogan{
    display: block;
    margin: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

#gestaltung{
    color: rgb(0, 51, 145);
}

#schoenheit{
    color: rgb(241, 185, 0);
}

#schutz{
    color: rgb(212, 24, 0);
}

#headerNav{
    height: 1.9em; /*Actual height is 1.7em. There was a space between #headerWrapper and #contentWrapper, whyever...*/
    margin: 0 0 -0.2em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.23em 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.headerNavLinks{
    margin: 0 0.4em;
    padding: 0 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border: 0.0625em solid black;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

.headerNavLinks:hover{
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

#headerNavActive{
    border: 0.0625em solid green;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

#contentWrapper{
    background: white;
    padding: 0.6em;
}

#contentHeading{
    margin: 0;
}

#content{

}

#content p:last-child{
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

#footer{
    background: darkgrey;
    padding: 0.6em;
}

#footerP{
    margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#scrollBackToTop{
    background: lightgrey;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){

    body{
        font-size: 15px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 545px){

    body{
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #headerHeading{
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    #headerLogo{
        margin: 0 0.8em 0 0;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px){

    body{
        font-size: 17px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){

    body{
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #headerLogo{
        margin: 0 1.2em 0 0;
    }

    #headerSlogan{
        margin: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){

    #wrapper{
        width: 768px;
        margin: auto;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1676px){ /* Just tried to make the content fit the height...*/

    html{
        max-height: 52.38em;
    }

    body{
        max-height: 52.38em;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px){

    #wrapper{
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any content fills available space by default, without CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: body{ height: 100vh; }

Comment: @amn That's not true. Only for block level elements, the `auto` width is 100% of the parent. Not so for other display options and not applicable to height.

Comment: Don't write a post that says '... will follow'. Only submit your post when you have provided all relevant information, otherwise you will lose many readers who won't come back after an initial reading. Secondly, show us at least your HTML code and indicate which part has to fill up the available screen.

Comment: @BramVanroy If you have block elements, then the height is filled by the block level boxes, as they stack up one below the other, expanding the computed height of the document element. If you have anything else, e.g. inline level boxes, they fill up available space left-to-right and top-to-bottom, again expanding available height. Meaning that either the question is completely vague or the answer is "you don't need to do anything, just generate content".

Comment: I thought what you meant was that a single block element will fill up 100% height of its parent, which is not true - only so for width. What I think OP asked was flex-like behaviour where an element (e.g. main content between header and footer) is 'stretched' (i.e. fills the available height) so that the header is at the top of the viewport and the footer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  height: 100vh; //sets the height of the website to fit the screen.(even if the content is too less)
  overflow-y:auto; // allows vertical scroll if the content is more.
}
```

Comment: @TilJungbluth I checked your code, the website looks good. what is your requirement? can you be more specific ?

Comment: Thanks. If you mean this, I want the website to always fit the full screen height, no matter if there's enough content or it's displayed on a 4k screen in portrait orientation. As you can see, the header and footer have specified heights, so I want the content section (#contentWrapper) to be as tall as it takes/needs to fill up the missing height (if there isn't enough content) of the website. Understood me? ^-^” (I'll soon add a newer version of the code with a solution.)

Comment: Oh, as I just saw, I wrote you almost the same as I wrote into the description... I'll think of how to describe it more specific and write it to you... ^-^"